# Как в IntelliJ IDEA изменить схему?

Tags: intellij-idea

Подскажите как изменить вертикальную линию (к примеру сделать чуть ярче) для читабельности. Все перерыл не мог найти((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставить светлую тему.

Comment: Нет, зачем светлую, я спрашиваю как линию изменить (ярче, толще и тд) Видел схемы где они хорошо видны и на темной